# In where Codeigniter call it's error page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter when some kind of error occur then its handle the error with its default error page. When database error occur it load error_db.php, when page not found it show error_404.php etc. But I want to know in where Codeigniter handle error and load those view. 
I need this because I want to show those error page into popup mode that why user will able to stay current page from where he want to do something and fail. Just like

```
if(!$success){
    $this->load->view('error_404'); // This will be my popup
}
```

But I do not want to do that with my custom condition in everywhere. So if I find that where CI handle and load those error view I could modify that to change the view type of error message.

Answer (score 0):

`APP_PATH/application/errors` is the location of the files you're looking for.

Edit:

The code is in APP_PATH/system/Exceptions.php